# Django CRUD :Update function is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I made CRUD in django. Update is not working while creating and deleting views are working.Please fix my problem.And tell me where i am lacking.

This is `views.py`:

```
from  .import models
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import readerRegistrationForm
from .models import Reader, books
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,RedirectView,UpdateView
from django.views import View
# Create your views here.

def done(request):
     return render(request,'done.html')
class addshowView(TemplateView):
     template_name='add&show.html'
     def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
          context= super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
          fm=readerRegistrationForm()
          stu=Reader.objects.all()
          cone=books.objects.all()
          context={'str':stu,'form':fm,'con':cone}
          return context
     
     def post(self,request):
          fm=readerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
          if fm.is_valid():
               fm.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/')    

class userdeleteview(RedirectView): 
     url='/'
     def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
          p=kwargs['id']
          Reader.objects.get(pk=p).delete()
          return super().get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)

class Updateview(UpdateView):
     def get(self,request,id):
          pi=Reader.objects.get(pk=id)
          fm=readerRegistrationForm(instance=pi)
          return render(request,'updateit.html',{'form':fm})
     def post(self,request,id):
               pi=Reader.objects.get(pk=id)
               fm=readerRegistrationForm(request.POST,instance=pi)
               if fm.is_valid():
                  fm.save()
                  return render(request,'updateit.html',{'form':fm})`
```

This is `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import fields, widgets
from .models import books,Reader

class readerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model=Reader
       fields=['name','email','comment']
```

this is `models.py`:

```
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
   #Create your models here.
   class books(models.Model):
           name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
           gener=models.CharField(max_length=200)
           author=models.CharField(max_length=200)
           isbn=models.BigIntegerField()

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

class Reader(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    comment=models.TextField()
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.comment
```

This is `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from boom import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.addshowView.as_view() , name='show'),
    path('updated/',views.done,name='done'),
    path('delete/<int:id>/', views.userdeleteview.as_view() , name='doNow'),
    path('update/<int:id>/', views.Updateview.as_view() , name='UpNow'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This is `updateit.html`

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to Reader Update Page!!</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <a href="{% url 'done' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Update</button></a>
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

this is `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load static%}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Base</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <div class="blockquote text-center"><h1 class="alert">Welcome!!</h1>
            <h1>This is My Virtual Book Stall!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        {% block body_block %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
   </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

This is `add&show.html`

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h1 class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert"><em>This is The Library U can Grab!!</em></h1> 
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Author</th>
              <th>Gener</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {% for st in con %}
          <tr>
              <th>{{st.id}}</th>
              <td>{{st.name}}</td>
              <td>{{st.author}}</td>
              <td>{{st.gener}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<form method="POST" class="table table-primary">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3 class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">Add member</h3>
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Register">
</div>

<div class="col-8">
   
    <h3 style="text-align: center;" class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">Show Data</h3>
    {% if str %}
    <table class="table  ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">id</th>
            <th scope="col"><strong>Name</strong> </th>
            <th scope="col"><strong> Email</strong></th>
            <th scope="col"><strong> Comment</strong></th>
            <th scope="col"><strong> Action</strong></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for st in str %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{st.id}}</th>
            <td>{{st.name}}</td>
            <td>{{st.email}}</td>
            <td>{{st.comment}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'UpNow' st.id %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button></a>
              <a href="{% url 'doNow' st.id %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {% else %}
      <h3>NO RECORDS NOW</h3>
      {% endif %} 
</div>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is `done.html`

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Information updated Successfully!!</h3>
    <a href="{% url 'show' %}">Click Me</a>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two functions separately for update.
Use this:

```
class Updateview(UpdateView):    
    def update(request, pk):
        pi=Reader.objects.get(pk=id) 
        fm = readerRegistrationForm(instance=pi)      
        if request.method == 'POST':
            fm = readerRegistrationForm(request.POST, instance=pi)
            if fm.is_valid:
                fm.save()
                return redirect('home')
        context = {'form':fm}
        return render(request,'updateit.html', context )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the about code gave error:-   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Updateview is missing a QuerySet. Define Updateview.model, Updateview.queryset, or override Updateview.get_queryset().

Comment: Hi there, hopefully you understand the error you have been shown here. This is due to the missing query set. Most probably 1. you have not been able to store the query set from the database. Now, the solution is either the "id"  is not being passed to the get parameter or is not being passed into the class function. Please try to console print the variable "pi" and check if you are receiving something there. Do a little change the queryset calling syntax. rather than, "pk=id", use "id=pk"

Comment: As well you will have to match it in the url path, what variable name you are passing from the url.